# Monthwise average linechart is not displayed

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I've created a linechart showing averages using Dimensional Charting javascript library dc.js. I'm displaying a rowchart, linechart, and barchart.

When I select one category then year wise average line chart and month wise average line chart display. But when I select one particular year and one category the time month wise average line chart does not display.

```
skuRowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row-spenders");
     yearPieChart = dc.pieChart("#chart-pie-year");
    yearLineChart = dc.lineChart('#Yearly-move-chart');        
    spendHistChart22 = dc.barChart("#chart-hist-spend22");
    moveChart1 = dc.lineChart('#monthly-move-chart1');        
        function reduceAdd(p, v) {
                ++p.count;
                p.total += v.sr;
                p.average = p.total / p.count
                return p;
            }

            function reduceRemove(p, v) {
                --p.count;
                p.total -= v.sr;
                p.average = p.total / p.count
                return p;
            }

            function reduceInitial() {
                return {count: 0, total: 0, average: 0};
            }

          var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
            var yearFormat = d3.time.format('%Y');
            var monthFormat = d3.time.format("%m");
            //var monthNameFormat = d3.time.format("%b");
            var monthNameFormat = d3.time.format('%m.%b');

            var 

spendData = [ 
{ct:'KF', kw:'Amazon', sr: '35978',sd:'12/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF', kw:'Amazon', sr: '32178',sd:'11/2/2016'},
{ct:'KF', kw:'Amazon', sr: '30978',sd:'1/2/2017'},
{ct:'KF', kw:'Amazon', sr: '28978',sd:'1/15/2017'}, 
{ct:'KF',kw:'Build',sr:'28343',sd:'12/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Build',sr:'29653',sd:'11/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Build',sr:'26343',sd:'10/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Build',sr:'28343',sd:'2/2/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Build',sr:'28343',sd:'3/26/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Homedepot',sr:'221206',sd:'12/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Homedepot',sr:'203206',sd:'11/27/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Homedepot',sr:'193206',sd:'10/2/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'wayfair',sr:'77794',sd:'12/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'wayfair',sr:'71794',sd:'11/9/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'wayfair',sr:'70794',sd:'1/9/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'wayfair',sr:'74794',sd:'2/19/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'wayfair',sr:'74794',sd:'3/21/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Houzz',sr:'408684',sd:'12/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Houzz',sr:'42684',sd:'11/22/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Houzz',sr:'46684',sd:'10/2/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Houzz',sr:'496684',sd:'1/2/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Houzz',sr:'49684',sd:'2/2/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'Houzz',sr:'49664',sd:'3/2/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'express',sr:'32004',sd:'12/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'express',sr:'30004',sd:'11/2/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'express',sr:'35004',sd:'10/2/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'express',sr:'35004',sd:'12/2/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'yahoo',sr:'115618',sd:'12/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'yahoo',sr:'12546',sd:'10/2/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'yahoo',sr:'65423',sd:'11/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'yahoo',sr:'25698',sd:'10/29/2016'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'google',sr:'404991',sd:'1/29/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'google',sr:'404991',sd:'2/2/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'google',sr:'404991',sd:'3/12/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'google',sr:'404991',sd:'3/3/2017'},
{ct:'KF',kw:'pingserach',sr:'273944',sd:'12/29/2016'}
];
     // d3.csv("hhh.csv", function (error, salesrank) { 
         spendData.forEach(function (d) {
                     d.sr = +d.sr;
                    d.Date = parseDate(d.sd);
                    d.Year = yearFormat(d.Date);
                   d.Month = monthNameFormat(d.Date);
                });
         var ndx = crossfilter(spendData);
         var all = ndx.groupAll();
        SkuDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.kw; });
        spendPerSku = SkuDim.group().reduceCount();
        yearDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.Year; });
        year_total = yearDim.group().reduceCount(function (d) {return d.sr;});
        exptAvgGroup = yearDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
        monthDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.Month; });
        exptAvgGroup11 = monthDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
        month_total = monthDim.group().reduceCount(function (d) { return d.sr;});            

        skuRowChart
            .width(350)
            .height(300)
            .dimension(SkuDim)
            .group(spendPerSku)
            .elasticX(true)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([6, 20]))
            .ordering(function (d) {
                return -d.value
            })
           // .cap(40)
            //.margins({top: -30, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
            .controlsUseVisibility(true);
        skuRowChart.data(function (group) {
            return group.top(50);
        });



        yearPieChart
            .width(250).height(250)
            .dimension(yearDim)
            .group(year_total)
            .innerRadius(60)
            .controlsUseVisibility(true);



        yearLineChart
            .width(380)
            .height(280)
            .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
            .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
            .renderArea(true)
            .valueAccessor(function (p) {
                            //console.log("p.value.average: ", p.value.average) //displays the avg fine
                            return d3.round(p.value.average, 0);
                        })
            //.brushOn(true)
            .elasticY(true)
            .xAxisLabel('Years')
            .yAxisLabel('Review Count')
            //.dimension(moveMonths)
            .dimension(yearDim)
            .group(exptAvgGroup)
            //.margins({ top: 10, left: 60, right:40, bottom: 60 }) 
            .margins({top: 0, left: 60, right: 30, bottom: 60})


            spendHistChart22
                .width(400).height(280)
                .dimension(monthDim)
                //.dimension(dateeddim)
               // .group(dateeddimGroup)
                .group(month_total)
               .xAxisLabel('Months')
                .yAxisLabel('')
                .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
                .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
                 .ordering(function(d) { return d.key })
                .elasticX(true)

                .elasticY(true)
                .margins({ top: 10, left: 60, right: 40, bottom: 60 }) 

                .controlsUseVisibility(true)
                spendHistChart22.xAxis().tickFormat(d => d.substr(3))




        moveChart1
        .width(380)
        .height(310)
        //.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(map(function (d) {return d.Month;})))
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .valueAccessor(function (p) {
                            //console.log("p.value.average: ", p.value.average) //displays the avg fine
                            return d3.round(p.value.average, 0);
                        })
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
        .renderArea(true)
        //.clipPadding(10)
        //.brushOn(false)
        .elasticY(true)
        .xAxisLabel('Months')
        .yAxisLabel('')
        .dimension(monthDim)
        .group(exptAvgGroup11)

        .margins({top: 40, left: 60, right: 30, bottom: 60})
        moveChart1.xAxis().tickFormat(d => d.substr(3))




        dc.renderAll();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pramod24/kk4j0bzn/4/

Comment: Wow, did you really format your question as code in order to get around the rule against using jsfiddle.net without providing code? That's... brave. Anyway, I fixed it and I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to watch out whenever you divide by something that is potentially zero.

dc.js won't sanitize your data very much, so when you see a blank chart, it's probably bad data.

Without trying to debug anything, I tried fixing the first thing that stood out to me, those divisions by `p.count` that don't check if `p.count` is zero.

You probably want your averages to drop to zero when the count is zero. (Technically I guess there should be gaps in the line, but I won't get into that unless you're interested.)

This seems to fix the problem:

```
            function reduceAdd(p, v) {
                ++p.count;
                p.total += v.sr;
                p.average = p.count ? p.total / p.count : 0;
                return p;
            }

            function reduceRemove(p, v) {
                --p.count;
                p.total -= v.sr;
                p.average = p.count ? p.total / p.count : 0;
                return p;
            }
```

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/q4aquukz/1/

Would you be so kind as to point to the example where you got the bad code, so I can correct it or leave a comment?

Comment: Great! If you got the bad code from SO or one of the dc.js examples could you please let me know where, so I can correct it?